# How to find out which cipher suites an iOS application uses?

Tags: ios, encryption, ssl

I'm trying to find out which cipher suites and SSL/TLS protocol an app uses. In the privacy policy it is written that it uses SSLv3 but when I tested the server of the app's developer using an SSL checker it said it supports TLS 1.2 1.1 1.0 and SSL 3.0. Is there any way to determine the cipher suites used and the exact protocol an app uses to send data to a server?

Answer (score 1):

You could install a web proxy on your router or a computer and there are even web proxies on iOS like Charles Proxy.

- https://www.charlesproxy.com/

There are great tutorials on the site above using the Mac / Linux / Windows version of this to debug and investigate ios / iPhone traffic. The iOS app to run this on the device itself is here: [Charles Proxy by XK72](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/charles-proxy/id1134218562?mt=8)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this tool https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest to grab detail information about Protocols, cipher suites, Handshake Simulation. It will help to know the configuration of any SSL web server.

Comment: but it wont tell which cipher suites an app uses to connect with its server

Comment: Checkout https://helpcenter.gsx.com/hc/en-us/articles/207831828-How-to-identify-the-Cipher-used-by-an-HTTPS-Connection

Comment: an app doesnt use a specific browser

Comment: Yes, app doesn't use the browser. Searched a lot and found this resource for your query's solutions https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52150/identify-ssl-version-and-cipher-suite